# FOS User change password form requires my pass for another account

Tags: php, forms, symfony, fosuserbundle

I've got portal where companies can have subaccounts for their employees and they can change their employees password. The problem is that when I'm trying to change it I have to write user's current password, but it doesn't accept it's password, only mine - currently logged in user, not the user I'm editing.

My controller:

```
  public function changePasswordAction(Request $request, $company_id, $id)
    {
        $company = $this->getCompany($company_id);

        $subaccount = $this->getDoctrine()
            ->getRepository('MyBundle:User')
            ->find($id);

        if (!$subaccount or !$company->hasUser($subaccount))
        {
            throw new AccessDeniedException();
        }

        $form = $this->createForm('fos_user_change_password', $subaccount);
        $form->add('save', 'submit');
        $form->handleRequest($request);

        if ($form->isValid())
        {
            $userManager = $this->container->get('fos_user.user_manager');
            $userManager->updateUser($subaccount);

            $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
            $em->flush();

            $this->get('session')->getFlashBag()->add('success', 'subaccount.flash.password_changed');

            return $this->redirect($this->generateUrl('subaccount_list', array('company_id' => $company->getId())));
        }

        return $this->render('MyBundle:Subaccount:edit.html.twig', array(
            'form' => $form->createView(),
            'company' => $company
        ));
    }
```

And yes, subaccounts and portal users are created with one entity.

Answer (score 0):

The form `fos_user_change_password` is only for the current user.
In this case, you must create a new form, edit the user and save it using the user manager.

An example (not tested):

public function changePasswordAction(Request $request, $company_id, $id)
    {
        $company = $this->getCompany($company_id);

```
    $subaccount = $this->getDoctrine()
        ->getRepository('MyBundle:User')
        ->find($id);

    if (!$subaccount or !$company->hasUser($subaccount))
    {
        throw new AccessDeniedException(); //You should send HTTP not found
    }

    $form = $this->createFormBuilder() // You should create a new form type here
        ->add('password', 'repeated', array(
            'type' => 'password',
            'invalid_message' => 'New password has not been repeated',
            'options' => array('required' => true),
            'first_options'  => array('label' => 'New password'),
            'second_options' => array('label' => 'Repeat new password'),
        )
        ->add('save', 'submit')
        ->getForm();

    if('POST' === $request->getMethod())
    {
        $form->handleRequest($request);
        if ($form->isValid())
        {
            $data = $form->getData();
            $subaccount->setPlainPassword($data['password']);

            $userManager = $this->container->get('fos_user.user_manager');
            $userManager->updatePassword($subaccount);

            $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager()->flush();

            $this->get('session')->getFlashBag()->add('success', 'subaccount.flash.password_changed');

            return $this->redirect($this->generateUrl('subaccount_list', array('company_id' => $company->getId())));
        }
    }

    return $this->render('MyBundle:Subaccount:edit.html.twig', array(
        'form' => $form->createView(),
        'company' => $company
    ));
}
```

Comment: yeah, but with FOS bundle I have to repeat password and also I have to give old password - way more secure then form with just providing new password. And I don't really know how to add field for old password and for repeating new password...

Comment: I have modified my answer. Now the password is repeated. I do not understand why you need the old password. An admin/user manager is not supposed to know password of users. To secure a little bit more, you can add a new password field that represent the current user password (the admin or the user manager).